# How to download file with http post Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I would like to know how I can **download** a **file sending parameters** by POST. For example I have an **invoice** where I have **saved the file path** and I want to **send that path through parameters** to download it. But now I can only do it with a GET:

**Server**:

```
app.get('/getfile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
            res.download('uploads/myExcelFile.xlsx', "myExcelFile.xlsx");
});
```

**Client**:

```
window.open('/getfile');
```

**Or**:

```
<a href="getfile" download="myExcelFile.xlsx">Download Text</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use express for that

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/files/:file', function(req, res, next){ // this routes all types of file
    res.download("./" + req.params.file);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

You can use this url (localhost:3000/files/myFile.txt) assuming the file exist sure

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set some header information, after that create file object and stream the file through respond.

```
app.post('/getfile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
          'Content-Length': stat.size,
           'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=your_file_name'
      });


      var file = fs.readFile(filePath, 'binary');

      res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=your_file_name');
      res.write(file, 'binary');
      res.end();
  });
```

In UI, create javascript form object and submit

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "URL");
form.submit();
```